# Making Site A Use Site B's wp-content Folder

Tags: uploads, hooks, core, constants, sync

I'm trying to synchronize two WordPress sites and on my way I've faced few challenges. One of the challenges is to either synchronize the wp-content folder of two sites or make one site use the wp-content of other site for ADDING and RETRIEVING multimedia content.

Normally a Wordpress site uses its own wp-content folder but how can we customize the WordPress so that it uses other site's wp-content folder.

Visuallization:-

[image]

**Constraints:-**

1. Site A and Site B are on different shared web hostings. Each having its own Cpanel.

Comment: WP uses `require` and `include` functions to load themes and plugin files. Doing what you ask means to use those functions to `require` and `include` files from an external server. For that you should enable [`allow_url_include`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) that is highly unsecure and disabled by default. In addition, WP expects paths (and not urls) in a several constants (`TEMPLATEPATH`, `WP_CONTENT_DIR`, `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`...) If you make these constants containg urls instead of paths I bet something will break even if `allow_url_include` is true.

Comment: I feel this would be impractically complicated between two different servers, especially with typical restrictions of shared hosting (I doubt you have SSH access to both to use rsync or something, right?)

Comment: @Rarst yes, you are right. SSH is disabled.